# How does one compute conditional expectation with respect to a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I can't wrap my head around the way to compute conditional expectation with respect to a continuous random variable. For instance, consider a probability space $(\Omega, A, P)$, where $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $A$ is a corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Let's define random variables $X(\omega)=\omega$ and $Y=\sin (\pi \omega)$. How does one compute the expression for $\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{B})$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$?

---

If $Y$ was discrete, such as
$$
Y = \begin{cases}
1,&\omega\in[0,1/2]\\
0,&\omega\in(1/2,1]
\end{cases}
,$$

then I understand that $\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{B})$ would be equal to
$$
\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{B}) = \frac{1}{4}\mathbb{I}_{Y=1}+\frac{1}{4}\mathbb{I}_{Y=0}.
$$

However, in the continuous case I'm not so sure. My intuition suggests that it's something like $\sin^{-1}(y)/\pi$; however, then
$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)) = \int_Y \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)d\omega = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\int_0^1 \arcsin(y) dy  \neq \mathbb{E}(X).
$$

Comment: Have you come across [Borel–Kolmogorov paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox)?  They are examples of the dangers of conditioning on an event of probability $0$, as the conditional probability measure may not be specified by the original probability measure

Comment: @Henry Thank you for bringing it to my attention! I’ve never heard of it before. So how can we avoid conditioning on an event with zero probability in this case?

Comment: For all $y\in Y(\Omega)$, we have $\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)=y\}=\{\arcsin(y)/\pi, 1-\arcsin(y)/\pi\}$, and there will be no bias between these outcomes; so $\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y) = 1/2$ and so $\mathsf E(X\mid\sigma(Y))=1/2$.

Comment: Also $\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X\mid Y)) =\int_{Y(\Omega)} \Bbb E(X\mid Y=y)\cdot f_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm d y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For instance, consider a probability space $(Ω,\mathcal A,P)$, where $Ω=[0,1]$ and $A$ is a corresponding Borel σ-algebra. Let's define random variables $X(ω)=ω$ and $Y=sin(πω)$. How does one compute the expression for $E(X∣\mathcal B)$, where $\mathcal B$ is the σ-algebra generated by Y?

Using $\arcsin: [0..1]\mapsto [0..\pi/2]$

A null events described by $\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)=y\}$, (where $y\in[0..1)$ ) will contain exactly two outcomes with no bias: $$\{\omega\in\Omega:Y(\omega)=y\}=\{\arcsin(y)/\pi, 1-\arcsin(y)/\pi\}$$  Therefore $\forall y\in Y(\Omega)~,\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y)=1/2$, so since this holds for any $y$, ...$$\mathsf E(X\mid\mathcal B)=(1/2)\mathbf 1_{Y\in[0..1]}$$